# Regular Expression avoiding characters up to code 255

Tags: java, regex

Dear Masters! Is it possible to ensure, that only characters with codes between 0 and 255 will be accepted by regular expression, but all with the codes up to 256 not? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can represent hex ranges in regex:

```
boolean matches = string.matches("[\\x00-\\xFF]+");
```

This will match everything which contains at least one character in the 0x00-0xFF range.

Answer (score 0):

You can match `[\x00-\xFF]`, i.e. the range of characters between 0 and 255.